# Alternative to Ubuntu One Music Store (non-US)

Tags: music, ubuntu-one

While I love the Ubuntu One Music Store, it doesn't really have a lot of artists I like in it. So is there any alternative Store (other than Jamendo and Magnatune, I'm looking for something more "mainstream") that works on Ubuntu for non-US users (eg: Amazon MP3 is not an option, since it's US only)?

I would love to be able to actually **buy** my music rather than illegally downloading it from the internet, but so far I failed to find a real alternative. Buying CDs in online stores and having them shipped to me isn't an alternative for me either. And options that require wine/crossover are out of question too.

So, how can I get my favorite music legally on Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't think this is Ubuntu specific, and therefore off-topic for this site.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without knowing what country you are in.

Comment: I'm in Switzerland.

Comment: @fluteflute This question is specifically asking for an option that "works on Ubuntu." If we assume that means "integrates with applications available on Ubuntu" then this question is on topic. At least one of the answers has taken it to mean that, and the others have at least addresses the issue of application integration.

Comment: @EliahKagan I think the bigger issue is online music stores that require DRM or that require you to use a Windows only. But Ubuntu integration is always a good thing!

Answer (score 2):

Amazon MP3 has a Swiss website at [amazonmp3.ch](http://www.amazonmp3.ch).

[Banshee](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/banshee) has great integration with Amazon MP3. Like the Ubuntu One store, then purchased music goes directly into your library.

```
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

You may need to first enable the Amazon plugin under
**Edit -> Preferences -> Extensions**.
You can then change the plugins settings to use the Swiss store under
**Edit -> Preferences -> Source Specific -> Amazon MP3 Store**.

[image: Amazon MP3 Switzerland Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Amazon UK may not integrate directly with Ubuntu's music programs, but you can certainly still buy from their web page :

http://www.amazon.co.uk/MP3-Music-Download/b/ref=sa_menu_dm1?ie=UTF8&node=77197031

What little online music I buy, I do it on my Android phone, which then uses Dropbox to sync the data to my PC.  I prefer to buy my music on CD's however, so that I can rip them to FLAC for better quality.  Ubuntu has many useful tools for this purpose - the two I use are "Audio CD Extractor" and "Sound Converter".

Answer (score 0):

Try the [7digital](http://7digital.com) online store, which is what backs the Ubuntu One Music store but which is available in most regions.  It includes a huge number of artists, including a lot of mainstream ones.

Their online store allows you to download your purchased music as DRM-free mp3s, though I'm not aware of any way to integrate that directly into either Banshee or Rhythmbox.